# Why difference in image resolution between firefox and chrome on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, display-resolution

I have system with following configuration:

[image]

When I open same website on both Firefox and Chrome, I could see a difference in image resolution. Firefox resolution is better than Chrome. 
Why is it so? Is it an issue with Chrome or Ubuntu ?

[image]
Please clarify.

Comment: what's you scaling setting? And are you zooming the website in any browser? Chrome has been famous for not respecting the OS dpi settings, result in tiny interface on hidpi screens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image in question (https://www.thehindu.com/static/theme/default/base/img/logo.png) is 547 pixels wide and 46 pixels tall. When displayed in its natural size, the image looks the same in all browsers.

[image]

For reasons unknown, the designers of the website have decided to display it with a width of 480 pixels.

[image]

This means that the browser must scale the image down. Each browser uses its own scaling algorithm; as you have noticed, Firefox and Chrome use different scaling algorithms, which give visually different results.

Morality: use bitmapped images at their natural dimensions, or else users of different browsers will see subtly different pictures.

Comment: Perfect! That explains the reason for difference in image clarity. Thanks.